# Can't install l18n, UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pip

Error occurs when I run

> pip install l18n

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8urtlamu\l18n\setup.py", line 99, in <module>
        long_description=open(os.path.join('README.rst')).read(),
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2135: illegal multibyte sequence
```

Tried but didnt work:

chcp 65001

Alternative concole: cmder

```
Config:
Windows 7
Python 3.6.4
Pip 10.0.1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is manifestly a bug inside l18n: in the `setup.py`, the *long_description* parameter is build by reading the `README.rst` file (this is a classic way to do that).

The trace back says: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2135. This is a classic error with utf-8 encoded text which contains non-ascii characters.

The source code is stored in Bitbucket:

```
long_description=open(os.path.join('README.rst')).read(),
```

The behavior of the `open` function changed in Python 3. You must set the file encoding which is utf-8 here:

A portable way to solve that is to define a function:

```
import io

def read(path):
    with io.open(path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        return f.read()
```

And to use it like this:

```
long_description=read('README.rst')
```

There is an [issue](https://bitbucket.org/tkhyn/l18n/issues/4/setuppy-raises-unicodedecodeerror-trying) about that.